# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine - Timestamp Annotation not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, timestamp, zend-framework2, zend-db

I've got the following problem: I need a `created_at` field.

I thought I solved the problem as follows:

```
 /**
 * @Version @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Form\Attributes({"type":"text"})
 * @Form\Options({"label":"Created at"})
 * @Form\Exclude()
 *
 */
protected $created_at;
```

Unfortunately this is not a `created_at` but a `lastmodified_at`.

Any ideas how I can prevent the field from updating its date on every save?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have an ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the table definition?

Comment: the type is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and standard is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as well...